# Assembly: How many bytes will be moved?

Tags: assembly, x86

On a test I had this question:

How many bytes will be moved by each of the following block of codes?

Block A:

```
mov cx, 384
rep movsb
```

Block B:

```
mov cx, 384
rep movsw
```

Comment: I know the way this question is posted sucks, but can someone answer please? I would like to know the answer :)

Comment: See "Intel 64 and IA-32 Architectures Software Developer’s Manual", Vol. 2A, page 3-557.

Comment: @MartijnCourteaux: I guess the OP is still sitting in the test, I will answer in about 5 hours.

Comment: @Michael: Which version? I've got version 050 of February 2014 and found there (3-557): "MOVNTQ—Store of Quadword Using Non-Temporal Hint".

Comment: @rkhb: June 2013. The title of the page is "MOVS/MOVSB/MOVSW/MOVSD/MOVSQ—Move Data from String to String".

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it appears to be asking for test answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MOVSB and MOVSW are instructions to move data from string to string. The Last letter indicates what the instruction is moving:

In block A you move 384 bytes (B). In block B you move 384 words (W) which amounts to 2 x 384 = 768 bytes.